# Custom styles in embedded widget without iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, widget

I'm creating a widget that will be embedded into user's page simply by including small piece of html and javascript.

Idea is similar to what Facebook and Twitter do with their "like" and "tweet" buttons. The only difference is that **I CANNOT implement widget with `iframe`** as they do. I need to make widget injected into regular DOM element which will be marked with special `data` and `class` attributes.

For example, solution may look as follows. This will be provided to user for inserting into his html:

```
<div class="widget-action" data-url="http://example.com"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s);
   js.id = id;
   js.src = "http://cdn/where/widgets/script/is/hosted";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
})(document, 'script', 'namespace-widget-sdk');
</script>
```

Widget's script which is hosted on CDN will do the job - creating necessary elements and injecting them into `widget-action` element.

This is pretty straightforward. What I'm trying to figure out - **what is the best way to deal with styles?**

What will be the most efficient way?

1. To create `<link>` element dynamically in the same manner as `<script>` and provide `href` attribute with CDN link hosting a `.css` file?
2. Or to inject styles with dynamically created `<style>` tag?
3. Other options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the output of the widget you can style it with a normal css-file.

You can just target the elements, and style them as you want to. If the widget doesn't really add classes & id's to the output, then put the widget inside an div, and then style it.

An example of the output would be nice, if further help is needed.